# Android SQLiteDatabase query with LIKE

Tags: android

I have 3 names, Allakhazam, Beatbox and Cunning in my NAMES Table.

```
public Cursor fetchNamesByConstraint(String filter) {

    mDb.query(true, DATABASE_NAMES_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_NAME }, KEY_NAME + " LIKE ?",
            new String[] { filter }, null, null, null,
            null);

    return mCursor;
}
```

I call the function with "A" as the filter, but my cursor is returning a 0 count when it should at least return me a 1. Anyone can see what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

this statement will return all the records whose keyname equals string specified by string, if you use wild card, then you can get desired results. Like:

```
mDb.query(true, DATABASE_NAMES_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_NAME }, KEY_NAME + " LIKE ?",
            new String[] { filter+"%" }, null, null, null,
            null);
```

Will Lists all the records starting with word in filter.

```
mDb.query(true, DATABASE_NAMES_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_NAME }, KEY_NAME + " LIKE ?",
            new String[] {"%"+ filter+ "%" }, null, null, null,
            null);
```

Will Lists all the records containing word in filter.

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me, I was looking at the wrong place.

Comment: Why do we need to add % symbol to the filter in the above code? @jeet

Comment: Because % is wildcard. The * is used for other elements in queries.

Answer (score 6):

```
    public java.util.Vector<Products> getsearch(String subcategory,String searchby)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(
            TABLE_PRODUCTS, 
            new String[] { SUBCATEGORY, MAIN_CATEGORY, PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_NAME, BRAND, PACKAGE_SIZE, PRICE }, 
            SUBCATEGORY + " LIKE '%" + subcategory + "%'",
            null, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this.....code.......

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID="row";
public static final String KEY_NAME="name";

public Cursor fetchNamesByConstraint(String filter) {

  Cursor cursor=mDb.query(true, DATABASE_NAMES_TABLE, null,"row LIKE '%"+filter+"%' or name LIKE '%"+filter+"%'",null, null, null, null);

  }
```

Comment: Without parameter binding code become unsafe with SQL injection vulnerability

Comment: sorry i can not understand.

Comment: I'll just pass filter = "criteria%'; DROP DATABASE .....; SELECT * FROM table WHERE row LIKE '%criteria"

Answer (score 2):

You can use Raw Queries.

```j
public Cursor fetchNamesByConstraint(String filter) {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " +
                    COLUMN_NAME + " LIKE '%" + filter + "%'" ;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return mCursor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give the filter with wildcards ;)

```
"A%"
```

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "%": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, nid, name FROM names WHERE name LIKE %?% Getting this error when I add " LIKE ?%"

Comment: you need to wrap your strings with single quotes

Answer (score 0):

The rest is up to our desing, cursor is commanly same

```
public ArrayList<AboneDataList> getAllPasssiveAboneByDate(String mDate) {
    ArrayList<AboneDataList> foodList = new ArrayList<>();
    AboneDataList food;
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    final String kolonlar[] = {DBHelper.COLUMN_A_ID,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_ABONE_NO,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_NAME,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_IS_STUFF,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_COUNTRY,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_CITY,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_TOWN,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_ADDRESS,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_PHONE,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_MOBILE,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_DATE_START,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_DATE_END,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_COUNT,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_IS_ACTIVE,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_CARGO,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_YURT_ID,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_JOURNAL,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_MAIL,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_BUSINESS,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_BIRTH,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_GENDER,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_ABONE_TYPE,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_A_MEDENI_TYPE};

    //String whereClause = DBHelper.COLUMN_A_JOURNAL + " = ? AND " + DBHelper.COLUMN_A_IS_ACTIVE + " = ? ";
    //final String whereArgs[] = {String.valueOf(mJournal),isActive};

    //Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_ABONE, kolonlar, whereClause, whereArgs,
      //      null, null, DBHelper.COLUMN_A_ID + " ASC");

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from " + DBHelper.TABLE_ABONE + " WHERE "
                          + DBHelper.COLUMN_A_DATE_END + " LIKE '%" + mDate + "%'", null);

    //Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_ABONE, kolonlar, null, null, null, null, DBHelper.COLUMN_A_NAME + " ASC");
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        food = new AboneDataList();
        food.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_ID)));
        food.setAbone_no(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_ABONE_NO)));
        food.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_NAME)));
        food.setIs_stuff(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_IS_STUFF)));
        food.setCountry(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_COUNTRY)));
        food.setCity(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_CITY)));
        food.setTown(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_TOWN)));
        food.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_ADDRESS)));
        food.setPhone(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_PHONE)));
        food.setMobile(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_MOBILE)));
        food.setDate_start(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_DATE_START)));
        food.setDate_end(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_DATE_END)));
        food.setCount(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_COUNT)));
        food.setIs_active(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_IS_ACTIVE)));
        food.setCargo(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_CARGO)));
        food.setYurt_id(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_YURT_ID)));
        food.setJournal(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_JOURNAL)));
        food.setMail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_MAIL)));
        food.setBusiness(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_BUSINESS)));
        food.setBirth(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_BIRTH)));
        food.setGender(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_GENDER)));
        food.setAbone_type(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_ABONE_TYPE)));
        food.setMedeni_hal(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_A_MEDENI_TYPE)));
        foodList.add(food);
    }
    database.close();
    cursor.close();
    return foodList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Cursor fetchNamesByConstraint(String filter) {

    mDb.query(true, DATABASE_NAMES_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_NAME }, KEY_NAME + " LIKE ?",
            new String[] {"%"+ filter +"%"}, null, null, null,
            null);

    return mCursor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<ListingStoreModel> searchListing(String kpName, String psu){
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursorCourses= db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM LISTINGDATABASETABLE WHERE listingKhanaProdhanName LIKE '%"+kpName+"%' AND listingPSUNo = ?", new String[]{psu}, null);
    if(cursorCourses.moveToFirst()){
    -----------------------------
    ----------------------------- 
    }
```