# Android SQLite LIKE escape wildcard

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

On Android Jellybean 4.1 is it possible to escape a LIKE wildcard character and still have the like use the index?

*Use:*

```
where field like 'xyz\_abc'
```

*as opposed to:*

```
where field like 'xyz_abc'
```

Does escaping wildcards work on Android?  And will it still use the index if the wildcard is escaped?

What I am currently doing is:

```
where field like 'xyz_abc' and lower(field) = lower('xyz_abc')
```

Which is horribly inefficient due to the wildcard character.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076561/android-sqlitedatabase-query-with-like take a look there it will help you probably!

Comment: If you don't want `_` as a wildcard then `field like 'xyz_abc'` should be `field = 'xyz_abc'`. `LIKE` isn't useful without at least one wildcard.

Comment: Thanks, but the column is case insenstive.  The source data could be any case eg, 'Xyz_abc' or 'xyz_Abc' there will however only ever be ONE lower('XyZ_AbC') in the column.  I'm trying to avoid writing a patch release to modify the database to convert everything to lower case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use the `ESCAPE` clause:

```
where field like 'xyz\_abc' escape '\'
```

See the section [The LIKE and GLOB operators](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) in the SQLite Documentation.