# getting force close error due to SQL query

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to search my notes whose title start with "n" but i dont know whats wrong with my query i got force close error.
Here is my log:

```
04-01 12:19:37.833: D/AndroidRuntime(676): Shutting down VM  
04-01 12:19:37.833: W/dalvikvm(676): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)  
04-01 12:19:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(676): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
04-01 12:19:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(676): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "%": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, title, body, cdate, passw FROM notes WHERE title LIKE n%  
04-01 12:19:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
04-01 12:19:37.913: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
```

Here is the code:

```
public Cursor search(String title) {
    Cursor mCursor =
            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY,KEY_CDATE,KEY_PASS}, KEY_TITLE + " LIKE" +" " + title +  '%', null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
 }
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9076679/1168654 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1243378/1168654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need literal between text

```
public Cursor search(String title) {
    Cursor mCursor =
            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY,KEY_CDATE,KEY_PASS}, KEY_TITLE + " LIKE '" + title +  "%'", null,
                    null, null, null, null);

            mCursor.moveToFirst();

        return mCursor;
 }
```

Comment: @Razin i recommend you to use placeholders and no this hardcoded approach.

Answer (score 1):

check this two links: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9076679/1168654) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1243378/1168654)

or just change this:

```
query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY,KEY_CDATE,KEY_PASS}, KEY_TITLE + " LIKE "+"'" + title +  "%'", null,
                null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The query should be something like:

```
select * from 'product' where product_name like 'crocin%'
```

once you add `' (single quote)` in the query, it should be working.