# query method in SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite, android-query

I want to know how to use query method that have `where` clause with `like` property.
basically what i want is to select all the columns WHERE C_NAME column is LIKE keyWord.

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
cursor = db.query(TABLE, null, C_NAME, new String[] {"like '"+keyWord+"'"}, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). They say:

```
selection   A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself). Passing null will return all rows for the given table.
```

so try this:

```
cursor = db.query(TABLE, C_NAME, new String[] {C_NAME + " like '" + keyWord + "'"}, null, null, null);
```

Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076561/android-sqlitedatabase-query-with-like) as well to see some examples on how to use the `selectionArgs` (4th argument above). That is where `keyWord` would have to go.

Comment: The answer from the other question is exactly what i was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this query work perfect for me

> Cursor cursor = db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[]{ COLUMNS }, ROW + " LIKE ?", new > String[] { "%" + name + "%" }, null, null, null, null);