# Why is my SQLite query with LIKE not working correctly?

Tags: android, sqlite

The query with LIKE does not work correctly. The result is given only if you enter an exact query. For example: Request: Invisible- result Invisible, request: Visible - no result. What's my mistake. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    userFilter = findViewById(R.id.userFilter);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    final DatabaseAccessSmeta databaseAccessSmeta = DatabaseAccessSmeta.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccessSmeta.open();
    String poisk = userFilter.getText().toString();
    List<String> quotes = databaseAccessSmeta.Search(poisk);
    databaseAccessSmeta.close();

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.region_list, quotes);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    userFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String query = (s != null) ? s.toString() : "";
            if (query.length() >= 3) {
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            } else {                   
                listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                adapter.getFilter().filter("");
            }
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
        
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {  }
    });
}
```

Database query:

```
public List<String> Search(String poisk) {
    List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
    String query;
    query = "SELECT * FROM smeta_name WHERE rabota LIKE '%"+poisk+"%'";
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        mylist.add(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex("rabota")));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return mylist;
}
```

Comment: for sure you should be careful with possible SQL Injection vulnerability on this code, review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076561/android-sqlitedatabase-query-with-like for using parameterized query for your LIKE clause.  Please note this doesn't address your question, I think more information is needed.

Comment: Also note that in `onCreate()`, there's likely nothing yet in the edittext for `getText()` to return. However with an empty input you should be getting everything off the database table. More info needed about the problem you're facing.

Comment: can you show your table name, and all column

Answer (score 0):

Used same use using room DAO
Below is my Dao class which have list of all queries

```
@Dao

interface DatabaseDao 

{
    
@Query("SELECT * FROM smeta_name WHERE rabota LIKE  '%'  ||  :title  ||  '%' ")

 fun getAllRides(title: String): LiveData<List<UpcomingResponse>>

}
```